# How to adapt this mySql query for Laravel eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Im doing the search feature and want to sort the posts by views total - each view row equals 1 view for the post. I made a query which works perfectly alone in MySQL, but can't remake it for Laravel.
There are posts and views, I'm trying to count views for each post and join them by adding to the post.

MySQL query:

```
SELECT posts.*, 
  (
     SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM views 
     WHERE template_id = 9 AND real_object_id = posts.id
  )
AS viewsTotal 
FROM posts 
ORDER BY viewsTotal DESC
```

this query does the job and returns:

```
id(post id), ..other post columns.., viewsTotal
5  5
3  3
4  2
9  1
8  0
10 0
11 0
12 0
13 0
```

The problem is when adapting it as Laravel query returns only those posts results that have at least one view row:

```
id(post id), ..other post columns.., viewsTotal
5  5
3  3
4  2
9  1
```

And other posts that have no views are lost which is not what I want.

Laravel eloquent query inside search method:

```
  $posts = new Post;

  // ... some other filters set in if statements if request fields are set
  $posts->where('type', $request->filterType);


  // and then sort if statement is always called
  if(isset( $request->sortByWhat ))
  {
        if( $request->sortByWhat === "new" ){
            $posts = $posts->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
        }

        else if ($request->sortByWhat === "pop") {
          $objectTemplateId = ObjectTemplate::where('title', 'post')->first()->id;
          $posts = $posts
           ->select('posts.*')
           ->leftJoin('views', 'posts.id', '=', 'views.real_object_id')
           ->where('views.template_id', '=', $objectTemplateId)
           ->addSelect(DB::raw('count(views.real_object_id) as viewsTotal'))
           ->groupBy('posts.id')
           ->orderBy('viewsTotal', 'desc');

           # dd($posts->toSql());
           # "select `posts`.*, count(views.real_object_id) as viewsTotal from `posts`
           # left join `views` on `posts`.`id` = `views`.`real_object_id` where `views`.`template_id` = ?
           # group by `posts`.`id` order by `viewsTotal` desc"

        }
  }

    $posts = $posts->paginate(5);

    $posts = $this->getPostImpressionsSearch($posts);

    return response()->json([
        'success' => true,
        'posts' => $posts
    ]);
```

There are posts, objectsTemplates, and views tables.

Posts have:
Id, title, content, type, user_id, timestamps

Views have:
id
templated_id (9, which represents that its Posts table),
real_object_id (post id, because its posts table row right know, could be article id, list id....),
user_id,
timestamps

P.S. ObjectsTemplates are like an indicator for views table so that I wouldn't need to create separate views tables for articles, lists, and all other resources:
id (in this case it's 9)
title ("Posts")

Comment: I'm assuming `$objectsCollection` here is something like `Posts::query()` ?

Comment: @apokryfos yes, corrected a little bit for more clarity.

Comment: Did you try using `join` instead of `leftJoin`?

Comment: Can you do a `dd(second query->toSql())` and share what laravel is actually making? Also I have concerns that `groupBy` might break the `paginate`

Comment: @apokryfos  added.


 "select `posts`.*, count(views.real_object_id) as viewsTotal from `posts` 
   left join `views` on `posts`.`id` = `views`.`real_object_id` 
   where `views`.`template_id` = ? 
   group by `posts`.`id` 
   order by `viewsTotal` desc"

Comment: @Nightwhistle, yes I did, does not make any difference :( The thing is, I was not even using joins in original query, but I cannot grasp how to adapt it for Laravel eloquent only by trying with joins.

Comment: Only place where I could see potential problem is that query filters rows where 

`->where('views.template_id', '=', $objectTemplateId)`

not sure how entire structure looks like but try debugging it on this place

Comment: @Nightwhistle views have type, and that type is template_id. In this scenario all id = 9 are posts. So results are only type of posts. Basically my query takes results which have at least 1 views in the table, when vanilla MySQL query takes all posts of type 9. For now I just added views row for each created post, that way all the posts are shown, but that's really a workaround though :/

Comment: I get that, but in case where you dont have any views you wont have `views.template_id` right? So in this case this `->where` will not match.

Comment: In case you wanted `ON` instead of `WHERE`, check how it's done here:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries (Advanced Join Clauses subsection, they dont have anchor here for some reason)